# How to use "almost" in different tenses?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Here is a situation: I am washing my car. My friends come and invite me to go to the cinema. I say: "Just a minute, I have almost washed my car".

Is it correct to use "have almost washed" here instead of "almost washed" or maybe should I use "have almost been washing" or "am almost washing"?

Comment: Most people would say "I've almost finished washing my car."

Answer (score 1):

> I have almost washed

is grammaticaly correct with the present perfect being used in the sense of indicating the recent past and the adverb "almost" indicating that the act is not finished.

I agree with Kate Bunting, however, that many, probably most, native speakers would be more explicit about the idea of finishing and say

> I have almost finished washing

Both are grammatical and comprehensible, but the second is more typical.

**EDIT** In response to the question below.

I reiterate  that "I have almost washed the car" is a valid construction. But because "have washed" implies completion, "have almost washed" implies action in the recent past that is not yet completed. English speakers tend not to rely on using mere tense to imply nuance. Therefore,

> I have almost completed X

and

> I have almost finished X

are quite common phrases. They are examples that are not at all rare.

What is also far from rare is the use of "almost" with the past perfect.

> We had almost arrived at the wedding when we got a flat tire.

Comment: Do you use "almost" with present perfect continuos tense? If so, could you give an example?

Comment: Please see edit above designed to address this question

Comment: Thank you, but I need an example with present perfect continuos tensen. Do English speakers ever say something like "I have almost been washing"?

Comment: Yes, but such uses are very rare and would frequently sound strained.."I have almost been wishing for something like that to happen" on the receipt of bad news concerning a person whom you dislike.